# PDI 8.1 repository is disabled

Tags: repository, pdi

I have installed PDI CE 4.4 in my personal computer, and I copy PDI CE 8.1 to some folder. When I run spoon.bat of CE 8.1, It run well, but the repository is disabled. How to solve this problem? My OS is Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: It likely caused by JDK change. I'm having such issue when I upgraded from JDK 8 to JDK 11, After rolling back, it showed up for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete or rename the pentaho config folder, `.pentaho` or `.Kettle`
is usually in `c:/Users/<your user>/.pentaho`, then try again with 8.2

Comment: please improve the formatting of your answer to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Following this guide for faster startup will also fix the appearance of the Connect button.
I use PDI 7.1 and this works as well.

[Link](https://blog.twineworks.com/improving-startup-time-of-pentaho-data-integration-78d0803c559b)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create either a File or Database repository as explained in the link below. Once the repository is created, Connect to it and you should be able to Import Repository.
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Products/Data_Integration/Repositories

Once imported, you should be able to go to File -> Open.